# How to close first windows , and open different window but in the same application (like Skype)

Tags: windows, qt

Hello all
Until now I was developing Qt MainWindow and always stay in this window , changing the content with QStackedWidget
But now I need to do something like to skype ,   the flow is 
user   open first window the login window after successful login , the window closes
And new different window opens with the user friends , now maybe it’s the same first window
That changed its look totally .. I don’t know.
How I manage this in Qt ?

Answer (score 0):

I remembered seeing a similar question at Qtcentre, here's the link: 
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4255-right-way-to-open-a-new-window

Comment: will try it the question is this the best way

Comment: @user63898: My guess is that, that link will give you an insight of different ways to do it

Comment: its not working im getting .. 'exec' : is not a member of login class
im inheriting from QMainWindow